# PHP Move_Uploaded_Files rename file

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, ftp

I'm trying to upload files through a jquery image uploader, but I'd like all files to use the variable 'fileName' to name the file that gets uploaded. As it works currently the file is uploaded using its original name. Any suggestions?

```
<?php

// A list of permitted file extensions
$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif');
$fileName = 'productimage';

if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){

    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
        echo '{"status":"error"}';
        exit;
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){
        echo '{"status":"success"}';
        exit;
    }
}

echo '{"status":"error"}';
exit;
```

Comment: it's `move_uploaded_file(source, destination)` if you want a different filename, then use a different destination. e.g. don't use `$_FILES...['name']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){
```

to

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$fileName)){
```